# Maximum likelihood estimator stuck at bounds

Tags: r, mle, log-likelihood, dirichlet

I'm working on setting up a maximum likelihood estimator to estimate the parameters for a dirichlet-multinomial distribution. Based on what I've seen elsewhere, it looks like the function `ddirichlet.multinom()` is working as expected, but when I pass to the log-likelihood function, `mle` seems to want to push it to the lower bounds! I figure I've mixed something up in either the function `ll()` or in the params for `mle()`, but can't seem to sort out what the issue is. Any guidance here would be much appreciated!

```r
library(tidyverse)

# setup a set of example data using a known dirichlet distribution
ex_data <- 
  gtools::rdirichlet(500, c(37, 5, 13, 120)) %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "universal") %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(.x, "...", "x")) %>%
  add_column(n = round(rnorm(500, 750, 20))) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("x"), ~round(.x * n))) %>%
  select(-n)
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...1`
#> • `` -> `...2`
#> • `` -> `...3`
#> • `` -> `...4`

ex_data
#> # A tibble: 500 × 4
#>       x1    x2    x3    x4
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1   153    23    81   498
#>  2   156    18    65   500
#>  3   208     6    40   479
#>  4   142    25    73   524
#>  5   181     9    54   497
#>  6   139    21    40   512
#>  7   184    24    49   495
#>  8   137    10    39   544
#>  9   153     9    44   519
#> 10   186    21    42   464
#> # … with 490 more rows

# density function for dirichlet multinomial distribution;
# based on checks w/other implementations, this seems to be working as expected
ddirichlet.multinom <- function(x, alpha, log = FALSE) {
  
  a0 <- sum(alpha)
  n <- sum(x)
  const <- lgamma(a0) + lgamma(n + 1) - lgamma(n + a0)
  
  pr <- vector(length = length(x))
  
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    
    pr[i] <- lgamma(x[i] + alpha[i]) - lgamma(alpha[i]) - lgamma(x[i] + 1)
    
  }
  
  prob <- const * prod(pr)
  
  if (log) prob else exp(prob)
  
}


# negative log-likelihood function
# seems to get stuck at the lower bound!
ll <- function(a1, a2, a3, a4) {
  
  x1 <- ex_data$x1
  x2 <- ex_data$x2
  x3 <- ex_data$x3
  x4 <- ex_data$x4
  
  log_likelihood <- vector("double", length = length(x1))
  
  for (i in 1:length(x1)) {
    
    log_likelihood[i] <- 
      ddirichlet.multinom(
        c(x1[i], x2[i], x3[i], x4[i]),
        c(a1, a2, a3, a4),
        log = TRUE
      )
    
  }
  
  -sum(log_likelihood)
  
}

# ll max likelihood estimation 
# depending on the example, it either gets stuck at the lower limit or it
# varies wildly with the starting params
stats4::mle(
  ll,
  method = "L-BFGS-B",
  start = c(37, 5, 13, 120),
  lower = c(1.0001, 1.0001, 1.0001, 1.0001)
)
#> 
#> Call:
#> stats4::mle(minuslogl = ll, start = c(37, 5, 13, 120), method = "L-BFGS-B", 
#>     lower = c(1.0001, 1.0001, 1.0001, 1.0001))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>     a1     a2     a3     a4 
#> 1.0001 1.0001 1.0001 1.0001
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: first it does not seem that your ddirichlet.multinomial works. It gives zero. looking at wikipedia, the function there does not give 0

Comment: havin `n <- rowSums(ex_data)` you could do `a<-log(n)+lbeta(n, sum(par)) - rowSums(log(ex_data) + t(lbeta(t(ex_data), par)))` to obtain the `ddir_mult` values. Replace NA/inf with 0. Note that this is different from your loop function

Comment: Oh wow, thank you!! I had been looking in the wrong area all of yesterday. I wonder where I went wrong with the initial setup for `dirichlet.multiom()` --- I though I had implemented the gamma version of the function (& it looked like it matched [this python implementation](https://datascience.oneoffcoder.com/dirichlet-multinomial-distribution.html), but the beta version here works well

Comment: Do you still need a solution or the comment is enough?

Comment: It looks like that addresses the lower limit push - now getting `NaN` for rows with a count of 0 (I believe this is coming from the `log(x)` call). From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution), the beta form "emphasizes the fact that 0 count categories can be ignored in the calculation." I've dug through [some of the referenced docs](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu//~elkan/edcm.pdf) and they say to ignore, but not explicitly how in terms of code. I'm wondering if `-Inf` can just be replaced with `0` in any vectors where it appears?